# Set a Google AdWords campaign objective for a URL with a query string

Tags: wordpress, google-ads

We will launch a Google AdWords campaign for our website.

On our website, we have a page to let users to send us a form for contact. After a user clicks on `Envoyer`, the page will be redirected to `https://example.com/?cf_id=20` (note that the id number in the end may change)

My colleague wants to set a campaign objective for this clicking of `Envoyer`. Does anyone know if it is possible to set an objective for that (e.g., a URL with a query `cf_id`)?

PS: Our website is built with WordPress and the form is built with `calderaforms.com`